# How to make custom toolbar like image which is given description

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-toolbar

**I am new in android development.Can anyone help me how can I customise the toolbar like the below image**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8yOn.png]

Comment: check here on how to use material design and themes http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"


        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delivery Location"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Jiwaji Ganj"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/tabUnselectedIconColor"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title_location" />
    </LinearLayout>
```